# Валидация Codeigniter и массива $_POST

Tags: php, codeigniter

*var_dum($_POST)* дает такой результат:

```
 ["name[]"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Vasile"
  }
  ["lastname[]"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Popov"
  }
  ["status[]"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["area[]"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
```

Далее валидация CI:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'Nume de părinte', 'required|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[2]|max_length[10]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname[]', 'Prenume de părinte', 'required|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars|min_length[2]|max_length[14]');
```

В итоге, при валидации, несмотря на то, что в name[] и lastname[] есть данные, пишет о необходимости заполнить эти поля.
В чем может быть причина тому?

Comment: Покажите как вы в форме вывели эти массивы

Comment: Если вы об этом:
<input type="text" name="name[]" maxlength="10" value="" placeholder="Nume">

<input type="text" name="lastname[]" maxlength="15" value="" placeholder="Prenume">

Comment: Потом данные переопределяются - это до валидации.( на клиенте сериализация формы).

parse_str($_POST['data'], $params);
   

   // POST PARENT
   $_POST['name[]']     = $params['name'];
   $_POST['lastname[]'] = $params['lastname'];